# get the last auto incremented id with medoo

Tags: php

I am posting a new row to the database but wanted to return the new auto incremented id in the response using medoo.  This seems to be generating a new blank row and returning that id.

```
<?php

   // Independent configuration
  require 'medoo.php';
  $database = new medoo(array( 
  // required 
  'database_type' => 'mysql', 
  'database_name' => 'db', 
  'server' => 'server', 
  'username' => 'user', 
  'password' => 'pw' 

));

   $database->insert("properties", array(
"name" => $_POST['name'],
  "address" => $_POST['address'],
 "address2" => $_POST['address2'],
  "city" => $_POST['city'],
 "state" => $_POST['state'],
  "zip" => $_POST['zip'],
 "lat" => $_POST['lat'],
 "lng" => $_POST['lng'],
 "website" => $_POST['website']
));

$last_id = $database->insert("properties", array(
    "propertyId" => "propertyId"
));

$propertyId = array(propertyId => $last_id);

echo json_encode($propertyId);

?>
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`insert()`](http://medoo.in/api/insert) method returns the last insert ID.

```
$insertId = $database->insert("properties", array(
  // etc...
));

echo $insertId;
```

Comment: yeah wouldn't let me before until 10 min had passed.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is no longer valid.

`$database->insert()` returns only `true` or `false`.
To get last auto incremented id you have to use `$database->id()`.

This code is taken from the official documentation:

```
$database->insert("account", [
    "user_name" => "foo",
    "email" => "foo@bar.com",
    "age" => 25
]);

$account_id = $database->id();
```